# How to pickle and unpickle instances of a class that inherits from defaultdict?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a class that inherits from `defaultdict` like this:

```
class listdict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, list)
```

I can pickle it, but when I unpickle it, this happens:

```
('__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)', <class 'listdict'>, (<type 'list'>,))
```

The class does not define any special methods of the pickle protocol. Pickling and unpickling of a normal `defaultdict(list)` works as expected. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: are you using `pickle` or `cpickle`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Types define how instances of it get pickled by defining one or more of a (fairly large) set of methods. Each has its own subtle behaviour. See [the docs on the pickle protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle#the-pickle-protocol). In the case of `collections.defaultdict`, it uses the `__reduce__` method:

```
>>> l = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> l.__reduce__()
(<type 'collections.defaultdict'>, (<type 'list'>,), None, None, <dictionary-itemiterator object at 0x7f031fb3c470>)
```

The first item in the tuple there is the type, and the second item is the tuple of arguments to pass to the type when instantiating it. If you don't override `__reduce__`, the first item will correctly change to your type, but the second item will not. This causes the error you see. A crude example of how you could fix it:

```
>>> import collections
>>> import pickle
>>> class C(collections.defaultdict):
...     def __init__(self):
...         collections.defaultdict.__init__(self, list)
...     def __reduce__(self):
...         t = collections.defaultdict.__reduce__(self)
...         return (t[0], ()) + t[2:]
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c[1].append(2)
>>> c[2].append(3)
>>> c2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(c))
>>> c2 == c
True
```

It's only a crude example because there's more to pickling (like `__reduce_ex__`) and it's all fairly intricate. In this case, using `__getinitargs__` may be more convenient.

Alternatively, you could make your class's `__init__` method take an *optional* callable, defaulting to `list`, or you could just use a function instead of a class:

```
def listdict():
    return collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go for the default parameter, as that seemed the simplest and most stable option.

Comment: Really? The function is *much* simpler :)

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve the issue of using `[0] * self._size` as default value, and getting the `_size` param persist over pickling.

Answer (score -1):

That error indicates that your 'listdict' class was expected to take one argument (the implicit self), but got two arguments.

Your class inherits from defaultdict, and defines an initializer. This initializer calls defaultdict's initializer and passes 'list' to it, which in this case may be either a function or a class. (I can't be bothered to check).

What you probably meant is to do this:

```
class listdict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, list):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, list)
```

Now, when listdict is initialised with a given list, it passes THAT list to the defaultdict's constructor, rather than passing a reference to the global list.

(That said, it's considered bad style to use a name that is the same as common global methods and classes, such as 'str', 'list', etc, for the same reason that you got confused).

Comment: `list` is a class. OP was not passing a particular list but the class which, as a callable, serves as a factory function for itself which is what `defaultdict`'s constructor takes as an argument. having `listdict` take `list` as an argument defeats the purpose of subclassing `defaultdict`.

Comment: it's bound to happen every now and again

Comment: The question, however, is "Was that intended?"  He may have been testing it out and planned to add more functionality to the class later.