# python class calls itself in __init__ using super

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, super

i have a code like this:

```
class sampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(sampleClass, self).__init__()
```

my question is that why it calls super of itself under `__init__` ?

i know that super is used for calling the parent class's `__init__`, (if I'm wrong tell me) ,  but here what does it do ?

Comment: super() returns the parent class.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? "i know that super is used for calling the parent class's ``__init__``" is exactly what happens here.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't call the `__init__` of it's self that's the correct syntax of `super` which the first argument must be the class itself (the class name that super will call its parent's `__init__`).

Read more here https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super

> **super([type[, object-or-type]])**
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates
> method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. [the first argument]

Comment: This doesn't really explain what is happening here, could someone elaborate? I'm interested as well.

Comment: @HannesZiegler I found this website useful https://realpython.com/python-super/#a-super-deep-dive

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understand, this type of class definition enables to differentiate new type classes from old type classes in Python 2. However, Python 3 is using only new type classes by definition. Therefore, this kind of implementation is not necessary if you are using Python 3 but it helps for back compatibility.

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7vou1s/what_does_object_in_class_classnameobject_do/dttx467/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

This link contains more information regarding differences of class definitions in Python 2 and Python 3.

Basically, you can turn your class definition into this if you are using Python 3.

```
class sampleClass():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

Comment: This definition of ``sampleClass`` is *not* equivalent to what is shown in the question. It will behave differently when used with multiple inheritance, failing to call its superclass.

Comment: Please check again and read carefully. It is exactly the same for Python. I even changed couple code of mine from the first type of definition to my type of definition and it works!

As you can see, in the question, `sampleClass` inherits `object`.

jsbueno explained what object is in here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043963/class-classname-versus-class-classnameobject)
. Therefore, there is no superclass that needs to be inherited in the question like you mentioned.

Comment: Again, in the case of multiple inheritance, say ``class C(sampleClass, dict):``, there *is* a superclass different from object. Superclasses are not static, that's the entire point of having ``super`` instead of calling the superclass by name.

Comment: See for example [Raymond Hettinger's blog on multiple inheritance](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for an explanation how the superclass can change via multiple inheritance.